# Caching in multi process application

Tags: python, python-3.x, caching, multiprocessing

I am implementing a multiple process application that:

1. Receives messages from a queue and queries the database to get additional information
2. Performs actions such as calling external webservices that return the results
3. Then it saves the results of the messages in the database

I am going to create 4 processes via Pool and execute map_async on it so that the pool creates 4 processes for me. Each process will perform the above 3 steps.

The issue is that I don't want to query the database each time because I get 10 messages per second. I can query the cache instead and update the database and cache in step 3.

However I want all of the processes to share the same cache. Can you recommend if I should use Memcache service to host the cache or should I use Pool messaging objects like Pipe/Queue/Manager/Shares Memory to share the cache?

The entire data from dB is 1GB in size and my machine has 36GB RAM

Comment: Are you running into actual performance issues with the database or is this all hypothetical. Modern db servers will cache what they read and return results from there if there were no changes. You might get some performance|latency improvement from key-value stores, but unless you are certain that it is your db that is the bottleneck I wouldn't. If your read query is slow consider making views and such. Optimising your database is simpler.10 transactions/s should be nothing substantial (unless you are being charged for lookups but as you know the db size I don't think that is the case).

Comment: I created a performance test whereby I sent 15K messages and queried the database and  then saved data in the database and queried it back. It started with 2.5secs per message for the whole time. 2s were spent on dB. I created indexes and now dB query takes 1s per request. I've created 4 processes so it will mean 3-4 msgs per second hence I am asking about the right caching strategy because our benchmark is 10msgs per request

Comment: Perahaps you can use the [`multiprocessing.shared_memory`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html) added in Python 3.8.